# OpenGL glTranslatef/glRotatef not working as I expect

Tags: opengl

I am trying to create a polygon and translate/rotate it when the mouse button is released.
I am able to do this if I redraw my whole polygon again by using `glBegin` and `glEnd` but I am not sure if I really need this as I have already drawn the polygon on the screen once and just want to use the same object and apply rotation/translation to it.

I am putting a snippet below.

```
if(state == GLUT_UP){

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(90,0,0,1);
    //  glTranslatef(50,-50,0);
    /*
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i (-40,40) ; //Specify li ne - se gme nt ge ometry .
    glVertex2i (-30 , -40) ;
    glVertex2i (0 , 20) ;
    glVertex2i (40 , 35) ;
    glEnd() ;
    */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    //  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: You really need to draw it again unless you only want to rotate the image that was created at the end, but then you would need to draw that image on a quad and rotate this. I think you should read more about the basics of GL as you seem to have a misunderstanding there.

Comment: Thanks.Actually I want to use the same image which was last created.Could you please explain what you mean by "darw that image on a quad"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please speak with me: **"I'll never put OpenGL drawing calls into event handlers again!"**

In a event handler you set some variable according to the event, then issue a redrawing call and in the rendering function you draw according to the content of the variables.

#### Update:

Also OpenGL does not "rememer" what you draw. You send drawing commands, OpenGL does its deed and then forgets about it. The only trace left are the fragments turned to pixels on the framebuffer. But the framebuffer contents are not affected by transformation or any OpenGL state changes. Only drawing affects the framebuffer.

Comment: thanks.So if I want to rotate the image from the previously rotated state ,how do I do that using OpenGL.

Comment: @code4fun: You redraw the whole thing but with the changes applied. That's how OpenGL is supposed to be used. Modern GPUs can deal with millions of triangles per second. Redrawing a handfull of triangles for your polygon is no effort for a modern GPU. What you must understand is, that OpenGL has no notion of "objects". All it sees are calls to draw single individual points, lines or triangles. It draws a point, a line or a triangle, and forgets about it right after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You donot need to write the whole code again:

In your display function (the same void function that you use as an argument to register the callbacks to glut window as `glutDisplayFunc(display)` ) put your code snippet above.

Inside your `glPushMatrix()`..`glPopMatrix()` sequence, put a variable(preferably `GLfloat` type) angle inside `glRotatef()` call along with your rotating axis. You can do the same for `glRotatef()` arguments.

If you want to rotate or translate using mouse or keyboard, then use `glutMouseFunc()` or `glutKeyboardFunc()` to register the callbacks with GLUT. If you want an animation, then you can register a function with `glutIdleFunc()`.

The code snippet will be:

```
void handler(...){
angle+=some_value;

//angle reset not so necessary but good,
 if you somehow are using that angle value somewhere else
  if(angle>360)
  angle=0;

glutPostRediplay();
}
```

keyboard:

```
handler(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
```

mouse:

```
handler(int button, int state, int x, int y);
```

idle function (for continuous animation)

```
handler(void);
```